# What's the difference between `destroy` and `remove` in konvajs

Tags: konvajs

I have create a shape object(like `konva.Rect`) and want to reuse it in some cases.

In the first place, add it to layer, and everything is fine, like drag, move .etc. And then `destroy` it from layer by some trigger event, and at some point in time, add it back to layer with `layer.add(rectObj)`, the shape lost some
properties like drag, but use `remove` will not.

I check the source code, but have no clue about this situation. The only difference is that delete `id` and `name` in `destroy()`,

It's seems too vague in documents.

> destroy()
>   remove and destroy self
>
> remove()
>   remove self from parent, but don't destroy

So want to know if use `remove` and shape object `id` and `name` will remain in layer, Is there any significant impact about the render or others?

If use `destroy`, how to make it works like first add to layer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I updated the docs. I hope it is more clear now:

https://konvajs.org/api/Konva.Node.html#destroy

> **destroy:** remove and destroy a node. Kill it forever! You should not reuse node after destroy().

https://konvajs.org/api/Konva.Node.html#remove

> **remove:** remove self from a parent, but don't destroy. You can reuse node later.

Comment: Could you add code to illustrate how to maintain a handle to the node and add it back in to the parent? Is it as easy as var node = new shape({}); layer.add(node); node.remove(); layer.add(node); or is there more to it ?